# Why does breaking out this correlated subquery vastly improve performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried running this query against two tables which were very different sizes - #temp was about 15,000 rows, and Member is about 70,000,000, about 68,000,000 of which do not have the ID 307.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM #temp
WHERE CAST(individual_id as varchar) NOT IN (
        SELECT IndividualID
        FROM Member m
        INNER JOIN Person p ON p.PersonID = m.PersonID
        WHERE CompanyID <>  307)
```

This query ran for 18 hours, before I killed it and tried something else, which was:

```
SELECT IndividualID
INTO #source
FROM Member m
INNER JOIN Person p ON p.PersonID = m.PersonID
WHERE CompanyID <> 307

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #temp
WHERE CAST(individual_id AS VARCHAR) NOT IN (
        SELECT IndividualID
        FROM #source)
```

And this ran for less than a second before giving me a result.

I was pretty surprised by this. I'm a middle-tier developer rather than a SQL expert and my understanding of what goes on under the hood is a little murky, but I would have presumed that, since the sub-query in my first attempt is the exact same code, asking for the exact same data as in the second attempt, that these would be roughly equivalent.

But that's obviously wrong. I can't look at the execution plan for my original query to see what SQL Server is trying to do. So can someone kindly explain why splitting the data out into a temp table is so much faster?

EDIT: Table schemas and indexes

The `#temp` table has two columns, `Individual_ID int` and `Source_Code varchar(50)`

`Member` and `Person` are more complex. They has 29 and 13 columns respectively so I don't really want to post them all in full. `PersonID` is an int and is the PK on Person and an FK on Member. `IndividualID` is a column on Person - this is not clear in the query as written.

I tried using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `NOT IN` before asking the question. The performance on the second query wasn't noticeably different - both were sub-second. On the first query I let it run for an hour before stopping it, presuming it would make no significant difference.

I also added an index on #source, just like on the original table, so the performance impact should be identical.

Comment: How many `IndividualID` element does your sub query returns?

Comment: You should be able to get an estimated execution plan for your original query. But it may not be too useful if there aren't indexes/statistics on the temp tables.

Comment: Get the query plan for both the queries and post in your question.

Comment: It's most definitely not the same code. In the first case you are trying to find the result of a function (`cast`) inside another query, without defining any type of relation between the two that could be used to limit the search. Using temp tables means you have no indexes or statistics, so you end up with a separate execution for each of the original rows. With temp tables SQL Server can't guess which type of searching is best and may well chose the wrong strategy

Comment: Switching from not in to a join might help. The horror story would be be running the subquery for every row in temp table...

Comment: Please provide the schema for the tables, and the number of rows in each.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson that's the nested-join strategy, which is probably what's going on here. That `cast` means the server has no way of knowing the contents of the outer query so it has to repeat the inner query for each value

Comment: What determines MemberID?  Is the relationship between PersonID and MemberID many to one?  It's not clear to me.  Maybe it's not clear to the optimizer.

Comment: @WalterMitty Ah, my bad. In an effort to streamline my example I've inadvertently created some confusion. What's labelled "MemberID" in the query has nothing to do with what's labelled the "Member" table - MemberID identifies a company, whereas the other IDs in the query relate to individuals. Sorry - will do a quick edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your query has two faux pas's that really stick out.  You are converting to `varchar()`, but you do not include a length argument.  This should not be allowed!  The default length varies by context and you need to be explicit.

Second, you are matching two keys in different tables and they seemingly have different types.  Foreign key references should always have the same type.  This can have a very big impact on performance.  If you are dealing with tables that have millions of rows, then you need to pay some attention to the data structure.

To understand the difference in performance, you need to understand execution plans.  The two queries have very different execution plans.  My (educated) guess is that the first version version is using a nested loop join algorithm.  The second version is using a more sophisticated algorithm.  In your case, this would be due to the ability of SQL Server to maintain statistics on tables.  So, instantiating the intermediate results actually helps the optimizer produce a better query plan.

The subject of how best to write this logic has been investigated a lot.  [Here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) is a very good discussion on the subject by Aaron Bertrand.

I do agree with Aaron on the preference for `not exists` in this case:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM #temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Member m JOIN
                       Person p
                       ON p.PersonID = m.PersonID
                  WHERE MemberID <>  307 and individual_id = t. individual_id
                 );
```

However, I don't know if this will have better performance in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

This line is probably what kills the first query

```
WHERE CAST(individual_id as varchar) NOT IN
```

My guess would be that this forces a table scan rather than using any indexes.